# Data is being deleted when internet is off

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using realm `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'` and the data is being saved and retreived successfully if the internet is working. but it does not return data if i switch off the internet of my device. 
Can anybody please suggest something ?

I have followed this link for learning about realm.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

here is my application class code

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

below is realmcontroller which is equipped with some code that i use to insert or retreive data

```
public class RealmController {

private static RealmController instance;
private final Realm realm;

public RealmController(Application application) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

public static RealmController with(Fragment fragment) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RealmController(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

public static RealmController with(Activity activity) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RealmController(activity.getApplication());
    }
    return instance;
}

public static RealmController with(Application application) {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RealmController(application);
    }
    return instance;
}

public static RealmController getInstance() {

    return instance;
}

public Realm getRealm() {

    return realm;
}

//Refresh the realm istance
public void refresh() {

    realm.refresh();
}

//clear all objects from Book.class
public void clearAll() {

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.clear(ServiceModel.class);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

//find all objects in the Book.class
public RealmResults<ServiceModel> getAllServices() {
    return realm.where(ServiceModel.class).findAll();
}

//query a list of services by category_id
public RealmResults<ServiceModel> getServicesByCategory(String id) {
    return realm.where(ServiceModel.class).equalTo("category_id", id).findAll();
}

//query a list of services by category_id
public ServiceDetailsModel getServiceDetails(String service_id) {
    return realm.where(ServiceDetailsModel.class).equalTo("service_id", service_id).findFirst();
}

//query a list of services by category_id
public void clearServicesByCategory(final String id) {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<ServiceModel> rows = realm.where(ServiceModel.class).equalTo("category_id", id).findAll();
            rows.clear();
        }
    });
}

// save a model in realm
public <M extends RealmObject> void saveModel(M object) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealm(object);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

//check if Book.class is empty
public boolean hasBooks() {
    return !realm.allObjects(ServiceModel.class).isEmpty();
}

//query example
public RealmResults<ServiceModel> queryedBooks() {

    return realm.where(ServiceModel.class)
            .contains("author", "Author 0")
            .or()
            .contains("title", "Realm")
            .findAll();

}
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend the [official Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) over that terribly outdated and terribly written tutorial you've followed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but right now i cant afford time to setup it again . any suggestions in the existing code ?

Comment: *any suggestions in the existing code ?* - throw it out and do it right. Never follow 2 year old tutorials when you're starting out with a new library

Comment: I'd say you're getting your data deleted either because you call clearAll() from somewhere you aren't showing, or you're modifying the RealmObjects and Realm gets recreated with new schema

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resolve your issue but try adding  `Realm.init(this);` before you set up the configuration.

Comment: That doesn't exist before Realm-Java 2.0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce tbh i don't understand why he has to use such an old version of realm to begin with

Comment: Because he followed a silly tutorial that says 0.82.1 is "the most stable version, and the latest is 0.89.0" -> when in reality, 0.88.3 was the most stable version at the time :D